# Automatic generation of targets based on bin_PROGRAMS and their SOURCES

Tags: autotools, automake

I have the following issue related to automake and I'd be happy for any advice/hint.

Let's have a general `Makefile.am` which creates  `n` PROGRAMS (2 in the ex.):

```
bin_PROGRAMS=p1 p2
p1_SOURCES=a1.c a2.c
p2_SOURCES=b1.c b2.c
```

I need to find some "magic" that can be included into any Makefile.am to generate something like this for all `bin_PROGRAMS`:

```
p1.1: a1.c a2.c
         ./some-script a1.c a2.c > p1.1

p2.1: b1.c b2.c
         ./some-script b1.c b2.c > p2.1
```

Is it possible? Ideally in some POSIX way...
Thanks for any idea.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think this is possible in a strictly portable makefile, as you need a pattern rule.

The pattern rule would look like this:

```
%.1: $(FIXME_something_goes_here)
        $(AM_V_GEN)$(srcdir)/some-script $^ > $@
```

(don't forget the `$(srcdir)`, to make sure your makefile works when doing vpath builds...)

The hard part is what to put for `$(FIXME_something_goes_here)`. Since Automake directives such as `$(p1_SOURCES)` are just normal Makefile variables, you should be able to automatically determine it with something like this:

```
$($(basename $(@F))_SOURCES)
```

although if you had illegal identifier characters such as `-` in your program names then you'd need to turn them all into `_` which would involve a bit more complicated expression.